# Messages not appearing on HTML using Django - messages

Tags: django, wsgi, django-messages

I know a lot of questions were around that topic, but I still cannot understand why in my case it's not working.
I have the function on my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("success")
            messages.success(request, 'Form submitted successfully.')
        else:
            print("error")
            messages.error(request, 'Error submitting the form.')
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'messages': messages.get_messages(request)})
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and I want that in my form on HTML will appear proper message on case if submit was succeed or no

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <span class="{{ message.tags }}-django-color">{{ message }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

As result, I have on logs of WSGI (i'm hosting everything on apache) that succeed or error message, BUT on my HTML form it's not appearing. What Im doing wrong?

P.S.
I have as described enabled INSTALLED_APPS, MIDDLEWARE and TEMPLATES in settings.py file

Thanks in advance, what I have miss